# Why would MessageBox.Show cause UnhandledException?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am working on an app that uses location services.  If I am debugging, the app works fine.  If I start without debugging, on the first run (after rebuild), it crashes when asking for authorization to use location services.  What happens is that if you let it sit, with the messagebox showing long enough (5-10 seconds), it crashes.  If I start without debugging again, it works fine (though it doesn't show the messagebox again, because somehow it gets past that line to the next line AFTER the conditional statement, where it sets first run false (I assume, because it doesn't show again).

Again, if I am debugging, no problems.  If I start without debugging, it dies.  This is the case when building in either the Debug or Release modes.

If I comment this block of code out, it executes without a problem.  If I click OK quickly, it executes without a problem.

```
 if (settings.FirstRunLocationPermission)
              {
                    string message = "Do you wish to use location services to see your location on the map? Your location is not being tracked. You can change this authorization in the settings.";
                    //if (MessageBox.Show(message,"authorization",MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                    //{
                    //      settings.AllowLocation = true;
                    //}
                    settings.FirstRunLocationPermission = false;
              }
```

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can explain to me why a simple messagebox checking for ok would cause a problem like this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the MSDN Documentation for the method, the reasons for the possible Exceptions is fairly clear:

[MDSN - MessageBox.Show Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598690%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

The other possibility is that there is some code running in the setter for the settings.AllowLocation property that is throwing the Exception. It would help if you included the actual Exception being thrown.

Comment: I believe that it must have had something to do with code running in the background, but not sure that it is the setter (this is the only code that accesses the setter). I did solve it by moving this block of code to the button event where you can show your own location. It was originally being run right after InitializeComponent(), so the UI had not been completely drawn yet, so apparently something in the background of that process interfered with the MessageBox.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are showing the MessageBox in OnNavigatedTo. If that is the case, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10502652/1798276) should help. The problem is that if the user does not press a button your app will crash since the framework thinks that navigation has failed.

And yes, this behaviour occurs to me only when debugger is not attached.

Comment: The key to this question is that it crashes after a particular time.  Your code must be running in a function which is time limited, such as an OnNavigatedTo, or a lifecycle handler.

Answer (score 1):

I use it this way, and it works :

```
var msg = MessageBox.Show("Do you .... ?", "Title", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
if(msg == MessageBoxResult.OK)
{
   //Do something;
}
```

Good luck