# Do code after OnNavigatedTo

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation, windows-phone-7.1

I Have Code get IdUsers From Other Page

```
String IdUsers;

        public Main_Wallets_Page()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
            MessageBox.Show(IdUsers);
        }


protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            String Id;
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("IdUsers", out Id))
                IdUsers = Id;
        }
```

The MessageBox Alway be Null. I Want to MessageBox Show the "IdUsers" after OnNavigationTo (Do not put the MessageBox IN  "OnNavigationTo").

How can i do it ?

Comment: Why don't you want to put the MessageBox.Show method call in the OnNavigatedTo? You need to gain access to variable data within the same control flow and seeing as the constructor only gets called once and before the OnNavigatedTo method, then this isn't the place to call MessageBox.Show.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use MessageBoxes in OnNavigatedTo because if the user does not press a button your app will crash since the framework thinks that navigation has failed. MessageBoxes in the constructor are equally as bad.

I can think of two options (I use #1 for these sorts of things):

1. Show the MessageBox in the `Loaded` event. But be careful it can be
   fired more than once. In the constructor you might add the handler for the Loaded event and then in the handler you'd detach from the handler so that it is called only once.
2. Use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` around the `MessageBox.Show` call so that it does not block navigation. That might still block the Dispatcher thread. If you really wanted to go this route you could use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` or a [TPL Task](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks).

I also have used `OnLayoutUpdated` in place of the `Loaded` event but I can't remember exactly why :) It seems like it might have been that the page hasn't yet displayed in `Loaded` and it has in the other event.

Answer (score 2):

If this value was initialized, you can store it in application isolated storage. Then, when constructor is called, you can read it from there. In this case value of user ID will be initialized and MessageBox won't show you NULL.

Answer (score 2):

**DO NOT** place `MessageBox` into `OnNavigatedTo` event.
Try to create an empty project with `MainPage` and `Page2`. Place button on `MainPage` to navigate to `Page2`. In `Page2` place `MessageBox` in `OnNavigatedTo` event. Then everythig will work fine if you Start Debugging from VS. BUT if you deploy and run it you will see that when you navigate to `Page2` you see `MessageBox`. Then don't do anything, just wait for about 15 sec. `MessageBox` will react as `Canceled` and **APPLICATION WILL BE CRASHED!** without any navigation to `Page2` or `MainPage`. The same thing happens if you use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` around the `MessageBox.Show`.
I assume that `OnNavigatedTo` event has a timeout which works only when app is deployed. So you should run your `MessageBox` when Navigation is competed. 
Everything works if you do

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) {
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    var lcTimer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200) };
    lcTimer.Tick += (s2, e2) => {
         (s2 as DispatcherTimer).Stop();
         if (MessageBoxResult.OK == MessageBox.Show("Test, don't push", "", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel))
             MessageBox.Show("OK");
         else
             MessageBox.Show("Cancel");
    };
    lcTimer.Start();
}
```

**Note:** If you have some code in `OnNavigatedTo` run above code at the end of `OnNavigatedTo`.

I liked what Austin Thompson(upvote) has adviced with `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`. But note that with this approach you need to place MessageBox inside the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` otherwise you will receive cross-thread exception. So the code is the following

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) {
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((stateInfo) => {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
            if (MessageBoxResult.OK == MessageBox.Show("Test don't push", "", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel))
                MessageBox.Show("OK");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Cancel");
        });
    });
}
```