# How to pin a contact tile to start from an application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have a hubtile in my application which opens contacts for dialling a number. Now, i wanted to pin that into the start page of windows and i am implementing this feature by using the below code:

```
private void Click_Tap(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShellTile oTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x =>               
        x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("flip".ToString()));

        if (oTile != null && oTile.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("flip"))
        {
            FlipTileData oFliptile = new FlipTileData();
            oFliptile.Title = "Hello WP8!!";
            oFliptile.Count = 11;
            oFliptile.BackTitle = "Updated Flip Tile";

            oFliptile.BackContent = "back of tile";
            oFliptile.WideBackContent = "back of the wide tile";

            oFliptile.SmallBackgroundImage = new Uri("Assets/Tiles/Flip/h.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
            oFliptile.BackgroundImage = new Uri("Assets/Tiles/Flip/h.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
            oFliptile.WideBackgroundImage = new Uri("Assets/Tiles/Flip/h.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
            oFliptile.BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/Flip/h.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
            oFliptile.WideBackBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/Flip/h.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
            oTile.Update(oFliptile);
            MessageBox.Show("Flip Tile Data successfully update.");
        }
        else
        {

            Uri tileUri = new Uri("/phoneNumberChooserTask.show()?tile=flip", UriKind.Relative);
            ShellTileData tileData = this.CreateFlipTileData();
            ShellTile.Create(tileUri, tileData, true);
        }
    }

    private ShellTileData CreateFlipTileData()
        return new FlipTileData()
        {
            Title = "",
            BackTitle = "",
            BackContent = "",
            WideBackContent = "",
            Count = 8,
           SmallBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/Flip/h.jpg", UriKind.Relative),
            BackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/Flip/h.jpg", UriKind.Relative),
            WideBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/Flip/h.jpg", UriKind.Relative),
        };
    }
```

The problem i am facing is when i run this on a device/emulator, Tile gets pin to start but when i click the tile on the start screen of my device/emulator debugger stops the process and the process breaks.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tile can not launch anything except your app. Add into uri some code that will be parsed by your app and then your app should call `phoneNumberChooserTask.show()`. For example:

`new Uri("/Chooser.xaml?tile=flip", UriKind.Relative);`

Then, in the Chooser.xaml (page in your project), in the OnNavigatedTo detect the title value in the Uri and call `phoneNumberChooserTask.show()`.

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful idea but then could you also tell me how can i perform the latter part through code because i am unable to perform this technique. It will be very kind of you if you could help

Comment: Get the number and call? Use [this sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394021(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: You want to say that i should normally insert this sample code in the file chooser.xaml in it's main constructor to execute and launch the contact page ?

Comment: Not the main constructor, but the OnNavigatedTo method. You should get the title and title can be found in the OnNavigatedTo parameters.

Comment: I have never used OnNavigatedTo method. I know it's concept but what could be the possible syntax to retrieve title ? i have tried but unale to get it coorect. Sorry for such trouble but could you help a little more with the detailed syntax ?

Comment: There is a lot samples at stackoverflow, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495520/do-code-after-onnavigatedto) even with a right code to call some your code at OnNavigatetTo.

Comment: protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
phoneNumberChooserTask.Show();
}
After this there is a definition for a for PhoneNumberChooserTask_completed but when i click on the tile i am not able to go back as the contact page refreshes itself. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Check the link that I posted above - [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495520/do-code-after-onnavigatedto). There is mostly exact sample that you need. Call honeNumberChooserTask via Dispatcher, do not call it directly.